Expo/Metro failing on MacOS Sequoia
I updated my MacOS to Sequoia and my previously working app is now giving me this:
 ERROR  Error: No locale data has been registered for any of the locales: en-US, en, js engine: hermes
 ERROR  Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. This can happen if:
* Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
* A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called., js engine: hermes

Nothing else has changed and it was working great immediately before the update. The network connection between my phone and the computer seems to be fine as I can see the build complete to 100% before this error is thrown.
